# XeLaTeX is not typesetting correctly with xeCJK after texlive update

Tags: xetex, texlive, mactex, xecjk

After a tlmgr update --self --all two days ago, I have had problems with xeCJK with XeLaTeX. Some documents won't compile at all, and others have strange problems. For simplicity, I tried the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Hiragino Mincho Pro W3}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

LATEX[1]（ラテック、ラテフ、レイテック、レイテックス）とは、レスリー・ランポート（ 英: Leslie Lamport）によって開発されたテキストベースの組版処理システムである。電子組版ソフトウェア TEX にマクロパッケージを組み込むことによって構築されており、単体の TEX に比べて、より手軽に組版を行うことができるようになっている。

\end{document}
```

[image: Output from MWE]

As you can see there are problems with punctuation and spacing. I'm not exactly sure what is going on. I looked in the tlmgr log, and I did see that there were updates to xetex, xelatex and fontspec. Could this be the cause of the problems?

If I comment out the xeCJK-related lines, then XeLaTeX typesets normally, without Japanese, of course.

Comment: Fixed in the latest xeCJK.

Comment: Okay, got it installed into my local texmf folder for the time being. It works. Thanks for the info. Hopefully, it will be pushed to texlive for updating soon.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto You can post that as an answer, I think.

Answer (score 4):

As Akira Kakuto mentioned in his comment, an update to xeCJK has been released (3.3.2 -> 3.3.3). It hasn't been pushed to texlive yet, but I downloaded it from CTAN and installed it in my local texmf folder. The problem is fixed.